# How to prevent user from cancelling a salesorder using js?

Tags: dynamics-crm

My mission is: after the user clicks on cancel order button, I need to check some data and if the data is true, I need to prevent from the button functionality to run and alert the user, where can I insert my code?

`Mscrm.Form.salesorder.CancelOrder` is a vanilla button and seems close to add or edit, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Either you can do a pre-update plugin, check the business logic and throw `InvalidPluginExecutionException` if it is satisfied
2. You can use custom action by customizing the OOB cancel button or by hiding it and introducing a custom cancel button to invoke custom action or script to alert